# При Instantiate обьекта иногда меняеться его центр

Tags: c#, unity3d

Ничего не пойму просто инстантиирую обьект 3д модель у нее меняеться центр иногда и она соответственно стает не туда куда надо. Код самый обычный

```
 Vector3 scale = characterN.model.transform.localScale; 
 GameObject model = Instantiate(characterN.model);
 model.transform.parent = MArray.instance.bkgModels.transform;
 model.transform.localScale = scale;
 Vector3 pos = MArray.instance.trLeft.position;
 model.transform.position = pos;
```

Comment: Тут что то связано с анимацией модели, буду разбираться

Comment: `Instantiate` создает копию объекта, вы уверены, что надо перезаписывать `model.transform.localScale`? Возможно, это лишнее?

Answer (score 0):

Согласен с aepot. В первое строке мы записываете в переменную размер characterN.model, потом создаете его и присваеваете ему ЕГО же размер. Попробуйте убрать строку с присваиванием размера

Comment: Там все дело в анимации было которую воспроизводила модель, я отследил эту анимацию и просто ее не вывожу. Я освобожусь ответ напишу, правда не знаю как это оформить.